# Reputation cap ignores reputation paid for bounty offerings

Tags: feature-request, bounties, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

I hit my reputation cap, offered a bounty, and got 13 more upvotes after offering the bounty.

The 13 upvotes didn't generate any reputation, so I was stuck at 150 reputation gained today (until one of my answers got accepted).  (No, they weren't Community Wiki)

Why can't I regain the reputation I offered for the bounty?

---

**EDIT**: Can this be changed?

---

It appears that this is an unwanted side-effect of the current implementation.

Can it be changed?

Comment: Has this changed since: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/can-you-offer-a-bounty-once-youve-hit-the-daily-rep-cap-and-then-earn-more-rep

Comment: Apparently it has.

Comment: other question is 100% wrong; I'm just going to delete it.

Comment: Then you should delete these four comments too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you "give away" rep such as through bounties or downvotes, it will decrease your rep cap by that amount. This has been noted in the past as a bug by several of us but I am unsure as to whether anything will be done about it because it seems to be too minor of an issue for some.

Comment: wow, this *decreases* your rep cap? I didn't realize that

Comment: Exactly.  Can it be changed?

Comment: I never thought that I'd see Jeff surprised at an SO implementation detail.

Answer (score 11):

Once you've hit the cap, you're done, other than having answers accepted. I believe if you hit the cap, downvote someone, and then remove the downvote, you stay at 199. I don't personally agree with it, but that's how it works.

Comment: I also don't agree with it.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't feel like an unwanted side effect at all. The OP hit the rep cap. Did you really want:

- I have 200 rep gain today and have hit the cap
- I give a 50 point bounty
- I get to earn 50 points more rep before hitting cap again

If that happened, rep cap days would just be "free offer a bounty" days since you would go up 200 and not really "spend" any rep on the bounty.

Comment: IDK about the OP, but I want that!