# How does proposing a bounty affect the reputation cap?

Tags: support, bounties, daily-reputation-limit

This was a question I originally intended to ask before [certain temporal anomalies caught my attention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51131/).

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22442/reputation-cap-ignores-reputation-paid-for-bounty-offerings/22444#22444), paying for a bounty will actually reduce your reputation cap. I searched more recent posts, but the majority of posts that deal with both reputation caps and bounty are about the reputation you *earn* from the bounty, not that lost from payment. Is this accurate to what actually occurs?

My main concerns draw from the following pool of questions.

1. Does paying a bounty actually reduce the reputation cap still?
2. After paying a bounty, am I considered to "reach" the reputation cap after getting 200 reputation worth of upvotes, or getting a net daily gain of +200 reputation from upvotes?
3. After paying a bounty, am I considered to "exceed" the reputation cap after getting over 200 reputation from non-bounty sources, or getting a net daily gain of over +200 reputation from non-bounty sources?
4. Can tactical bounty assignment be used to aid in avoiding the criteria for certain cap-related badges?

There were a few other questions I figured, but they could all be derived from the answers to the above questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reputation cap is currently only based on votes. You can spend as much as you want on bounties and anything else and this should not affect your limit.

> Does paying a bounty actually reduce the reputation cap still?

No

> After paying a bounty, am I considered to "reach" the reputation cap after getting 200 reputation worth of upvotes, or getting a net daily gain of +200 reputation from upvotes?

200 reputation period. Not net, but period.

> After paying a bounty, am I considered to "exceed" the reputation cap after getting over 200 reputation from non-bounty sources, or getting a net daily gain of over +200 reputation from non-bounty sources?

After you pay a bounty, you can get 200 reputation from up votes. If you paid a 500 reputation bounty, you could get a net -300 that day purely from up votes.

> Can tactical bounty assignment be used to aid in avoiding the criteria for certain cap-related badges?

You would need to elaborate on that.

Comment: To elaborate, if posting a bounty did affect the reputation cap, I was curious if it was then possible to use crafty bounty payment to basically raise the bar or otherwise mar your ability to hit the reputation cap for a particular day, preventing the acquisition of Mortarboard and other related badges.

Comment: *"200 reputation period. Not net, but period."* From this answer, I take that if someone got 100 upvotes and 100 downvotes in a day, that person would wind up capped with a net 0.  That's because there is a cap of 200 points coming in, regardless of things that "cost" the person rep, like downvotes or posting bounties.  *"Not net, but period."*  Is this correct?