# How do bounties affect the rep cap?

Tags: discussion, bounties, daily-reputation-limit

Just curious. This is what my rep audit looks for today:

```
 1   3436375 (15)
 2   3481588 (10)
 2   3481588 (10)
 2   3481612 (10)
 2   3481612 (10)
 2   3481656 (10)
 1   3481612 (15)
 1   3468630 (2)
 2   3481741 (10)
 1   3481741 (15)
 1   3481656 (15)
 2   3481886 (10)
 2   3481892 (10)
 2   3481886 (10)
 3   3481979 (-1)
 2   3481920 (10)
 2   3481886 (10)
 1   3481892 (15)
 2   3481892 (10)
 2   3455456 (5)
 2   3482217 (10)
 2   3482217 (10)
 1   3482217 (15)
 8   3455456 (-50) << bounty offered
 2   3483197 (10)
 2   3483197 (10)
 2   3483353 (10)
 2   3483353 (10)
 2   3483353 (10)
 2   3483353 [6]   << capped from here onwards
 2   3483353 [0]
 2   3483197 [0]
-- 2010-08-14 rep +242  = 4784
```

It seems like you rep lost via bounty can't be "recovered" past the daily cap (unlike points lost due to downvotes).
Is this by-design?

Comment: Consider adding this as an answer to [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51257/how-does-proposing-a-bounty-affect-the-reputation-cap).

Answer (score 8):

I just confirmed this.  I hit the rep cap today on Mi Yodeya, offered a bounty, and subsequently gained an upvote on a newly-asked question.  My rep did not increase.

So, offering a bounty does not give you more earning potential for the day.

*Received* bounties are different: they completely ignore the rep cap.  You can earn 200 rep through votes, and then earn more from bounties (and also from acceptances).  This makes sense, as otherwise it would never make sense to offer a bounty of more than 200 because the rest would be rep-capped away.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, bounties are totally and completely immune to the rep cap.

Comment: I know they are when you are receiving bounties, but it doesn't seem like you can gain back points you lost by offering a bounty - not past your reputation cap. If that makes sense.

Comment: @Null yup, I think that is by-design.