# Upvote with no points

Tags: support, reputation, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I'm facing a strange behavior here, I got an upvote on a question (the upvote is still here, never been removed), but in my reputation tab I have

[image]

and in the statistics pop-up

[image]

Has anybody ever seen that problem?

Comment: Did you hit a rep cap?

Comment: well I'm at 243 today...

Comment: There's a +200 daily limit on reputation earned from upvotes. Congratulations on hitting the cap for the first time!

Comment: My bad I thought it was 250

Comment: May these be your problems ;) Oh - and congratulations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you've reached the reputation cap for the day (200). Once you've received 200 reputation in one day, you will no longer gain any reputation that day, regardless of how many votes you receive. [Bouties are an exception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61011/167443)

Comment: Accepts *are* the exception

Comment: oh I see... and what would be those *exceptions*?

Comment: ahhhhh  
limit = hit