# Possible bug in the bounty accounting software?

Tags: discussion, bug, bounties

To recreate this 'bug', follow these steps...

1. Start out on a fresh day
2. Get 200 rep and cap out
3. Put out a 50 point bounty

**Behaviour**: Your rep for the day is 150 and frozen there until the clock resets.

**Expected behaviour**: you should be able to collect another 50 rep points because you're at 150 for the day.

**Desired behaviour**: you can recover the 50 points and then put out another bounty. Repeat until your bounty count is maxed.

**Ideal behaviour**: All rep forfeit once the cap it hit goes into a bucket from which bounties can be opened.

Note: it is part of the 'ethos' on travel.stackexchange.com for high-rep users to open bounties on unanswered questions posted by those who '*cannot afford*' to open bounties. It's fun. Join us in June for the 5th anniversary "Bounty Bonanza".

Comment: What I know, once you reach 200rep, your account will be marked as capped even if you lost all the rep that day, it will still counts towards the badges that counts how many days you got the cap. Just saying..

Comment: Does it work otherwise if you do not cap out? For example, can you get to 180 rep, put a 50 rep bounty on something and get 70 more rep?

Comment: @J.Constantine, yes that works. But I want to put everything over 200 into bounties.

Comment: I was just wondering if it was possible. Then your request is no more than fair in my opinion. Have my upvote.

Comment: @GayotFow That working (getting to 180, dropping 50 on a bounty, getting another 70 reputation from upvotes) sounds like the bug, personally.

Comment: @J.Constantine please promote your comment into a full answer. I think it's helpful.

Answer (score 6):

It is by design - [How do bounties affect the rep cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61010/how-do-bounties-affect-the-rep-cap)

> bounties are totally and completely immune to the rep cap.

Both inbound *and* outbound.

Answer (score 2):

As already said this is [totally by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61010/how-do-bounties-affect-the-rep-cap). I wondered myself if this is a good thing or not.

It gives you the ability to start a bounty on a question of someone else without costing you anything (if you hit the rep cap after starting the bounty again). This seems to be a good thing, or isn't it?

I think that also exposes a problem.

1. Bounties shouldn't go for free. You can agree on that or not, but that is the opinion of the team on this.
2. It allows you to freely give reputation away to friends, which is unfair. You were the person that earned it and you shouldn't just give it away. Allowing to just give reputation away opens the door to abuse.

Considering the above, I think the system is good as it is now.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you can get any amount of rep lower than the daily cap, spend some of that on bounties, and you will be able to gain the rep spend on bounties again for the day. Say you have 180 rep gained for the day, place a 50 bounty and gain another 70. Net gain is 200 and 50 extra is spent on bounties.

I think this system is great. Bounties are a great thing, they serve as a little nudge for people to answer questions and any incentive to place bounties is in my opinion good and any discouragement to place bounties is bad, especially since bounties are a rather selfless action (in many cases). It does not matter if someone can get 250 or even higher daily reputation this way, as their net rep gain will still be 200.

This not working if you already got the daily cap seems like a bug to me, especially since the rules say bounties do not count towards daily rep caps. Of course this shouldn't enable being able to get badge credit for getting the cap multiple times. And in an ideal case, the badge credit would also be awarded in the following scenario: gain 180 rep, place 50 bounty and gain 20 more rep.