# Bounties AWARDED (not received) vs rep cap

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

I understand that bounties received do not contribute at all to the rep cap.  Are bounty awards immune to rep caps as well?

Scenario

```
 - [+204] gained 300 rep from votes (capped at 200)
 - [+ 50]  received a +50 bounty
 - [+ 60]  answered 4 questions
 - [-  4]  downvoted 4 answers (note: this can be recovered)
```

One would sit at +310 rep for the day.

If you then awarded a bounty

```
 - awarded a +500 bounty
```

Are you at -190 effectively for the day, or can this be "recovered" from upvote reps, like the downvotes?  So is the outcome

- -190; or
- -94  (96 recovered from upvotes)

**Proposal:** If it isn't the latter, can we make it so?

EDIT: It seems Grace has asked this before but that was a long time ago. You know how things age here on SE...  I'm making a `proposal` here as well.

Comment: For starters, you don't pay the reputation when you award the bounty, you pay it when you first *post* it. The reputation is gone whether or not it goes to anyone. As far as answering your question, though, the answer is that, [being completely dissociated from the rep cap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51257/how-does-proposing-a-bounty-affect-the-reputation-cap), capped votes are still capped regardless of spending on bounties. You don't get refunded.