# What happens to my reputation if I place a bounty after hitting the rep cap?

Tags: support, bounties, daily-reputation-limit

If in one day I earn 350 reputation (capped at 200), and on the same day I offer a bounty of 100, at the end of the day, have I gained 100 or 200 reputation?

**Edit**

I Confirm that [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51261/225842) address my problem.

Comment: @Bart Hmmm, I think it's different

Comment: I think you should still get the badge. This can be confirmed by using the Data Explorer, hopefully someone will write proper query soon. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The question is not about getting the badge!

Comment: @Antonio so the question is not clear. Why did you mention the badge if it's not relevant?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The OP was just referring to hitting the rep cap. I've edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### You will gain only 100 rep that day.

You can **earn** 200 rep with upvotes per day. If you invest some of that in a bounty you can't earn more on that day.

The reputation cap does not mean you can **gain** 200 rep per day at most (apart from bounties and accepted answers), it means you can **earn** 200 rep.

[It happened to me on the 2013-06-18 here on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172011/juergen-d?tab=reputation&sort=graph&StartDate=2013-06-24%2020:58:49Z). (How can I link that?) I gave 200 bounty away, I hit the rep cap and in total I only gained 2 points that day.

Comment: It seems a good answer, can you put some source just to be sure? And can you explicitly say if at the end of the day I will have 100 or 200 more reputation than the day before?

Comment: How comes you gained 2?!? You should have gained zero, or not?

Comment: @Antonio: Good question. That day I deleted a post of mine that had 1 downvote and got the 2 points back. If this is intended not counting towards the rep cap - no idea.

Comment: Probably it counts for the day you had posted that post, can it be?