# Reputation cap on question upvotes?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348687/highlight-arguments-in-function-body-in-vim) has 46 upvotes --- that should make 200+ rep. I've only gained about 150. What gives? I haven't hit the daily 200-rep gap ever. I know that for sure since I set the bounty to nicely even out my rep to 3000.

A bug or something else? For instance, [my rep changes for Feb 21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308668/progo?tab=reputation) describes +60 rep for upvotes but my question received 13 upvotes (65 rep).

Similar [to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22442/reputation-cap-ignores-reputation-paid-for-bounty-offerings) but I didn't hit the rep gap *before* offering bounty.

Comment: Basically yes, there is a cap on reputation 200 points from votes per day. Points from acceptances and bounties aren't capped.

Answer (score 4):

If you expand the detail on that post, you'll see that "13 votes" correspond to **12 upvotes** (+60) + **a bounty** (-350). So the totals displayed are correct here.

Also, the reputation cap is *per day*. Votes on your question spanned many days, as shown in your profile.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't consider a bounty a 'vote'. Neither was the rep cap really about the daily one. Because the votes have been split to multiple days, what's the reason for rep loss?