# Remove design deficiencies in reputation cap: when the limit imposed is effectively below 200

Tags: feature-request, bug, bounties, daily-reputation-limit

Previously I had an HNQ answer, gained a lot, hit the cap and the upvotes kept coming. Then I got a downvote and the clock was reset with +198. Frustrating, but almost explained  to be understable in [What is the daily reputation cap and how can I hit it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/what-is-the-daily-reputation-cap-and-how-can-i-hit-it) and  [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes).

What I do not understand at this point is either the reason/algorithm behind this or the way it is explained. Why is this downvote not compensated by all those uncounted upvotes?

But besides that I recently had another run and hit the cap. This should have given me another point towards Epic badge. But *after* I hit the cap I started a bounty of 50 and got stuck at daily +150 despite further upvotes coming in *after that*. No progress towards Epic, no compensation for the rep deduction.

This is so far and in effect similar to [Bounty should not effectively reduce reputation limit to difference below 200](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231637/bounty-should-not-effectively-reduce-reputation-limit-to-difference-below-200).

But the answers and comments there seem to be both unsatisfactory, dimissive and not 'official' either. I further fail to see why the feature request there got a status-declined tag.

Concerning the lost reputation this needs a clearer answer:
If the bounty is offered *before* the cap is hit, do following upvotes count then? If 'yes', this is an inconsistency that needs addressing. And having tested this right now: it is *yes.*

What kind of incentive does this create? If Jon Skeet was to care about rep again it seems that he would have to offer rep at close after midnight and not incur any punishment from that. The same person offering a bounty closer to before the next midnight gets the full brunt?

That's strange. I tend to be more generous after being fed, after my time-zone appropriate, main meal of the day. Yet, the algo incentivises generous behaviour right after 0000 GMT/UTC?

Concerning the badge progress: this is a bug, in  my opinion, in  the algo design and the wording: I have hit the rep-cap, so it should count as progress towards badge (or the explanation needs expansion rewording from "Earn 200 daily reputation 50 times" to "you have to hit the date reputation cap with exactly >+200 rep, just hitting the rep once during the day does not count if you loose rep until 0000 hours" or soemthing similar.)

Reading the rationales given most of the time here around the rep-cap it seems to me that both instances are just bugs or lazy programming/implementation that are tried to be explained away retro-actively.

My request: it would be much more consistent to really just cap the daily limit to be 200, not that any upvotes after hitting the cap are discarded for rep. Let every upvote count as long as the daily rep sum is below 200.
Really and "and/or": When the re-cap limit is hit immediately increase the badge progress.

Comment: Mostly that's a flag, once limit is reached, flag is true, upvotes after don't count anymore, badges are evaluated periodically and they check the rep and not the state. This may explain the difference. Changing how the rep cap works sounds adding complexity for a corner case from my window. Maybe the badge could be computed differently

Comment: Reputation calculations are horrifically complicated. Generally, they work as folks expect them to unless you think about them too hard or get unlucky; occasionally, things get weird. [Here's a relevant discussion of what actually "counts" for the purpose of the Mortarboard/Epic/Legendary badges](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=6696771#6696771)